# fetch request in for loop only returns data from last iteration

Tags: json, request, fetch

I'm making 14 fetch requests, the 'date' changes within the loop on each iteration.
So I should be printing the fetched data for each specific date.

The program only prints data of the very last date possible in the loop.

removing the "setTimeout()" causes 429 errors. but some of the logs are of date other than the last. removing it gets rid of the errors, but the data is all of the last date.

```
for(i=0; i<14; i++){

        // update current_date 

        setTimeout(()=>{
            var date_url = 'url_and_params' + current_date + 'rest_of_url';
            fetch(date_url)
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()     
            }).then(data=>{

                console.log(data[0].stat1);
                data1.push(data[0].stat2);
    
            })
        },5)
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the current date doesn't actually update, once you initialise it with the current date, it stays the same and never updates, you need to reset the current date each iteration, I don't know how you get the date so I have left a comment there, hope it helps, let me know if works! Take care and good day

```
for(i=0; i<14; i++){

        // update current_date 

        setTimeout(()=>{

            current_date = //get the current date each iteration

            var date_url = 'url_and_params' + current_date + 'rest_of_url';
            fetch(date_url)
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()     
            }).then(data=>{

                console.log(data[0].stat1);
                data1.push(data[0].stat2);
    
            })
        },5)
        
    }
```

Comment: Somewhat helpful, but printing the current_date before the setTimeout prints them all individually, but printing it after setTimeout(()=>{ only prints the very last date after all the correct dates were printed.

Comment: @beatmaister well I think you could declare the variable in for loop instead of declaring it in setTimeOut and then using that instead see if that works, if not I will think of something else

Comment: Also maybe try making another function like getDate() which returns current date and call that in setTimeOut

Comment: moving the date changing function inside setTimeout() does print the correct dates and data per iteration, but a lot of the requests are giving errors 429. which is 'too many requests' error, though its only one per iteration.

Comment: If it's possible can you send me the updated code ?

Comment: I figured out that it was too many requests for the API at the same time. I sent a different type of request that I didn't need to loop through, and that worked. Thanks a lot!